# Regex to match a unlimited repeating pattern between two strings

Tags: regex

I have a dataset with repeating pattern in the middle:

```
YM10a15b5c27
```

and

```
YM1b5c17
```

How can I get what is between "YM" and the last two numbers?

I'm using this but is getting one number in the end and should not.

**/([A-Z]+)([0-9a-z]+)([0-9]+)/**

Comment: Do you want `aa` to be any string of similar letters, or just two similar letters?

Comment: Should it get `1234code` or `d1234coded` from `ddd1234codeddd`?

Comment: I fail to see anything repeating in String 1, and only a 1 repeating in String 2.

Comment: From `YM10a15b5c27` i should get `10a15b5c`
I think I will use a number in the end

Comment: If I use `/([A-Z]+)([0-9a-z]+)([0-9]+)/`, it will get the `10a15b5c2` but I want `10a15b5c`

Comment: What language/environment are you executing this pattern in?  Do you need to capture all three components? or are you just trying to extract the middle portion?  Please show how your input data can vary by offering a few more input strings and your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture exactly two characters in the last group:

```
/([A-Z]+)([0-9a-z]+)([0-9]{2})/
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
/^(?:([a-z]+))([0-9a-z]+)(?=\1)/
```

`^` matches the start of the sentence. This is **really** important, because if your code is `aaaa1234aaaa`, then without the `^`, it would also match the a`aa`a of the end.

`(?:([a-z]+))` is a non-capturing group which takes any letter from 'a' to 'z' as `group 1`

`(?=\1)` tells the regex to match the text as long as it is followed by the same code at the starting.

All you have to do is extract the code by `group(2)`

[An example is shown here](https://regex101.com/r/BVKUAk/4).

Comment: Thanks, but the "aa" can be any letter [a-z]. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

If you want to match these strings as whole words, use [`\b(([a-z])\2)([0-9a-z]+)(\1)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/nwXLFb/1).
 If you need to match them as separate strings, use [`^(([a-z])\2)([0-9a-z]+)(\1)$`](https://regex101.com/r/nwXLFb/2).

## Explanation

- `\b` - a word boundary (or if `^` is used, start of string)
- `(([a-z])\2)` - Group 1: any lowercase ASCII letter, exactly two occurrences (`aa`, `bb`, etc.)
- `([0-9a-z]+)` - Group 3: 1 or more digits or lowercase ASCII letters
- `(\1)` - Group 4: the same text as stored in Group 1
- `\b` - a  word boundary (or if `$` is used, end of string).